# How to set Precision with a variable?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy

I get confusing output from the code below.  If I put a number after a variable value, the precision gets set just fine.  But if I put a variable after the backtick, MMa multiplies the values.

Three part question:
Can anyone make sense of the confusing outputs?
Why does N[] give `delta` the correct precision but not `center`?
How can I create a value for `center` with precision equal to `prec`?

```
center = -1.40115518909205060075`50
center // Precision
center = N[-1.40115518909205060075, 50]
center // Precision
```

(*
-1.4011551890920506007500000000000000000000000000000

50.

-1.4011551890920506008

20.1465
*)

```
prec = 50
delta = N[(3*10^-19), prec]
center = N[-1.40115518909205060075, prec]
delta // Precision
center // Precision
```

(*
50

3.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000*10^-19

-1.4011551890920506008

50.

20.1465
*)

```
center = -1.40115518909205060075` prec
center // Precision
```

(*

-70.0578

MachinePrecision

*)

Comment: Remember that `N` does not increase the precision of a number.

Comment: @bbgodfrey  It increases the precision of delta in my code.

Comment: Why not use `SetPrecision[]` instead?

Comment: `3*10^-19` is an exact (infinite precision) number, and `N` in this case reduces it to a precision of 50.

Answer (score 2):

`` center = -1.40115518909205060075`prec `` won't work. You simply can't use variables in such expressions because the input processor is not programmed to pass expressions like `` 1.23`n `` to an evaluator. It interprets them as `1.23*n` and passes that to the evaluator.

I don't know why the input processor works like this, but it has worked that way for as long as I have used *Mathematica*.

Comment: The situation is similar to that of numbers in alternate bases and numbers in abbreviated exponential notation: `2^^1001` and `2*^5` work, but `x^^1001` and `2*^x` don't.